# Netlogo: Built-in function to calculate the expected profit

Tags: netlogo

Sorry for long post. I am newbie in agent-based modelling. So please accept my apology in advance if my question sounds stupid. I am trying to model a scenario where framer (i.e. agent) decides which type of crop should be harvest in different types of fields to increase the profit. The farmer agent has a budget i.e. the amount of money that can be spent on farming each time step equal to $100.

The farmer operates a farm that is subdivided into nine fields, which are arranged in a 3x3
cellular grid. Each field is of the same size. Water availability varies spatially across the fields with a rating of either 1 (driest), 2 (moderate),
or 3 (wettest). The manner in which water availability varies across the fields (i.e. randomly).
 The farmer must choose among three crops. As initial parameter settings, the crops have the
following characteristics:

```
            Yield    Price   Costs    Minimum Water Req.

Crop 1      300        20       15              3

Crop 2     200        12       10              2
Crop 3     100        7        5               1
```

Each crop requires a certain amount of water to grow. Crop yields will only be realized if the crop is
planted in a field with at least the crop’s minimum water requirement.
Now the problem is that I couldn't find any function in Netlogo that calculates the permutation or combination of crop, field, and water requirements to calculate the expected profit. Any help would be high appreciated.

Comment: you are correct, there are no built in functions for such optimisation problems. Do you have an algorithm for solving the problem? There is an extension that might be what you are looking for - see the Mixed Integer Linear Program (MILP) Solver at https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Extensions

Answer (score 1):

I believe you describe a linear programming problem.

Useful functions for solving Simplex Linear Programming problems are in NumAnal extension, which does not come bundled with NetLogo but which you can get as follows:

In NetLogo, under Tools / Extensions ... you can find **NumAnal**, probably with no green check-mark.  Select it.  On the right, you have buttons to install it, and then one to add it to your code. When you click those, it should now get a green checkmark and you should have a new line in your code "extensions [ numanal ]", and you are now able to use those commands, with the "numanal:" prefix, for example, numanal:simplex.

The documentation for it is in the folder where it was installed.  But where is that?
Sadly, the documentation for where extensions are downloaded is **not current**.
https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/extensions.html#where-extensions-are-located

After exhaustive search by date-modified, I actually found the folder on my Windows 10 laptop here: c:\Users\condor\AppData\Roaming\NetLogo\6.1\extensions
( Note the "\Roaming\" ).

That folder has a README.md text file, and a pdf document named "NumAnal-v3.4.0" explaining how to use it, and an examples folder with code.  It is a little dense.

Here's a link to the basics of how to describe a Linear Programming problem, which is beyond the scope of StackOverflow.  You can find help via Google.

Here's one 8 minute video ( as of 24-Nov-2019) that might help you figure out if this is what you need.

Simplex Algorithm Explanation (How to Solve a Linear Program)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RO5477EKlXE